# Usage of 'of' vs 'for'

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between 'process of registration of application' and 'process of registration for application'?

Comment: Hello, Anupam. Though you probably can't find any reference to the question you ask, please don't fail to add attributed links to where you've come across both of these expressions.